# How do I indicate that a post is a duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicates

This post [what are the disadvantages of rooting your device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7224/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-rooting-your-device/7225) was migrated over from StackExchange. It's (not surprisingly) a question that has been answered before. What is the right way to indicate that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the flag link.  It brings up a whole slew of options for specifying why you're flagging it.  If you choose "it doesn't belong here" the first option is to mark it as an exact duplicate.

Comment: Actually ... it isn't an "exact duplicate," it should just be linked.

Comment: @Amanda - I considered it close enough to flag it as such.  The question that already exists might cover more than the question linked in your original post, but the one you linked would certainly duplicate some of the answers from the existing question.  I think the decision to either link the offending question to the existing one or simply close the offending question is up to the discretion of the mods, in the end.

Comment: Ah, thanks. that makes sense. So if I mark it as an "exact duplicate" a mod will decide how to handle it, I won't get knocked for using "exact" inexactly.

Comment: @Amanda - Not being a mod I obviously can't offer the definitive answer on that, but since there's no option for "this is _almost_ an exact duplicate" my answer above is how I presume the system works right now.  It's how I've been treating it and I haven't noticed my flag weight go down.

Comment: "Flagging" a post just brings it to the moderators' attention. We then get to decide what to do with it (if anything). Once you get enough reputation, you'll get the option to vote on closing posts, including duplicates.

Comment: Let me just mention: We really appreciate when people bring things to our attention. We can't be everywhere at once.

Comment: @Al Everett - How many people are actively flagging posts and comments for you guys?

Comment: Not many, although the more active "gardeners" have enough reputation points now that we often don't need to get involved.